# Same index for all (sub-)directories?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, directory, indexing

I was wondering if it was possible to write some .htaccess page that makes the server use an index.php file in a SINGLE directory as the index file for every directory/sub-directory on my server, rather than placing the exact same index.php in 200+ directories.
If my description isn't clear, what I essentially mean is:
/files/index.php is to be used as the index for, for example, /files/morefiles, as well as the index for all directories and sub-directories within /files/, even though those directories would not have an index file themselves.
Thanks to all in advance.

EDIT: The php file generates different output based on the directory; To be specific, it lists the contents of the current directory if a certain cookie is set. So, unfortunately, URL rewriting won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) every path that ends with a `/` to the index.php.

Something like that:

```
RewriteBase /files
RewriteRule /$ index.php
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the php file generates different output based on the directory; To be specific, it lists the contents of the current directory if a certain cookie is set. Unfortunately this method doesn't work as the index file always behaves as if it's located in /files. Thanks, though.

Comment: You can, just use the `$_SERVER` variables, `REQUEST_URI` should do the job, however there are other variables that could also be used, just do a `print_r` on `$_SERVER` and try out what fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be a simple .htaccess in the 'main' dir:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^(*.)$ index.php [QSA]

RewriteRule (^|/)?index.php index.php [QSA]
```

If you need to switch working dir, in index.php:

```
<?php
   chdir(realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH))));
?>
```

With possibly some checks if you're still in you /files directory or lower.